# How to change LoadMask text in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

Is there a way to change `Ext.LoadMask.msg` on ExtJS 4.1 MVC Application globally?

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?145538-Override-default-loading-mask-msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with

```
// changing the msg text below will affect the LoadMask
Ext.define("Ext.locale.##.view.AbstractView", {
    override: "Ext.view.AbstractView",
    msg: "Loading data..."
});
```

for the most cases. Call this right after/within the onReady() function. Set ## to your locale language

Comment: I'm using ExtJS MVC and have no `onReady()` function at all. I tried placing and loading it from my `view` MVC folder. No effect.

Comment: @webbandit You simply have already one as a default in your MVC App but you can have a second for your localization.

Comment: What does it mean by `##`

Comment: @AshwinP As written below the code-box in my post: `Set ## to your locale language`

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.define("Ext.locale.de.view.AbstractView", {
override: "Ext.view.AbstractView",
loadingText: "Uebertrage Daten..." });
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this at the onReady function:

```
if (Ext.LoadMask) {
    Ext.apply(Ext.LoadMask.prototype, {
        msg: 'Загрузка...'
    });
}
```

Or like this at the your locale.** file:

```
Ext.define("Ext.locale.**.LoadMask", {
    override: "Ext.LoadMask",
    msg: "Загрузка..."
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(myPanel, {msg:"Please wait..."});
myMask.show();
```

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.LoadMask

Comment: this one applies `LoadMask` to certain Component only. In your case - `myPanel`. I'm searching for global solution for whole Application.

Comment: Use Ext.getBody() to get your entire window. Call this at appropriate place in your code. and pass the value to LoadMask()

Comment: I have lots of `LoadMask`s in my App. I should call this method for every mask I have?

Comment: That is the only way i think.. If you need to change the message at single sort then i feel u need to override the LoadMask method. But the better way is create a function like mask: function(body, msg) { new Ext.LoadMask(body, msg)}    and call this function wherever needed.